# Cost of storing objects into request for JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, object, jstl, resourcebundle

We have legacy applications which soon they will start to use common jsp pages. However in terms of used technologies each of them are using different view technologies. Shortly, they can use jstl in these pages.

I want to store my bundle implementation in request in order to be used by JSTL like this

```
  request.setAttribute("bundle", getBundle());
```

Our bundle has maybe 10000 entry.

My question:

Does storing big objects in request bring extra cost?

Update: Our bundle is static. (Per server there is only one instance of it.) I mean that we will have just a reference in the request object.

Maybe I should clearly state my requirement. The common pages that have already existing  has already implemented. And this implementation is sharing a very different bundle implementation. It is different than java.util.ResourceBundle . That is why I could not use jstl fmt tags.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? bundle is not something you save in request. May be if you explain your requirement we can provide more help.

Comment: @Jigar Joshi - org.life.java, @CoolBeans I updated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are reusing already created bundle then I guess storing should not cost you (Considering the fact that - request is also Java object and  will just have a reference to another collection which holds some objects), but if you are creating the bundle in each request call then that would be costly, again not from the storing perspective but time taken for creating a bundle with 10, 000 entries each time and also for garbage collection.

Answer (score 3):

All this costs you is the cost of stuffing an object pointer in to a hash map, which is, while not zero, effectively zero. It's in fact, like, up to 20-30 bytes total (depending on whether you're running 32b or 64b JVM mostly).